# Selenium CSS_Selector looking for an element with specific text is turning out a 'NoSuchElementException'

Tags: python, css, selenium, css-selectors

I'm having an issue with looking for an element with a particular text attribute utilizing CSS_Selectors in Selenium. Here is the current line of code I have:

element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.adTypeItem[text='CLASS']")

I've had trouble using the attribute selector brackets in CSS_Selectors in the past, and clearing this up would really go a long way to better understanding how to use CSS_Selectors in the future.

Please note - i'm not looking for a element with a class, but rather the actual text that is displayed with that element.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the only place on the page with the text "class" displayed? If so you can try:

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT('CLASS'));
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT('CLASS'));
```

Comment: It's not a HREF, 'CLASS' is just the text that is displayed on the element I am trying to locate. Also, i'm trying to only use a CSS_Selector, as its the a scripting standard we have in our automated codebase. Like, I can get my script to locate that specific element using an XPATH locator, but not a CSS_Selector.